# generating code coverage report for android test project

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage

i am trying to get a coverage report for my android junit test project and following [this guide](http://blog.rabidgremlin.com/2010/11/19/android-tips-generating-a-coverage-report-for-your-unit-tests/) to do so

```
android update test-project -m <path to app project> -p <path to test project>
```

worked fine. it generated a build.xml and updated project.properties,
local.properties and proguard.cfg.

but when I change directory to test project directory and enter command

```
ant coverage
```

it gives me this error.

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "coverage" does not exist in the project "My Project Test".

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I am using windows xp.

Comment: Which SDK Tools version are you using? If it is 14 or later, you need to use `ant emma debug install test` instead of `ant coverage`

Comment: @Torsten: you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which SDK Tools version are you using? If it is 14 or later, you need to use `ant emma debug install test` instead of `ant coverage`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Java build Path
2. Go to Source
3. Change Default output folder from: `ProjectName/classes` to `Project/bin/classes`

Answer (score 0):

Try ant all clean emma debug install test in the test project root after cleaning, updating and building both the projects