# Unable to get Emma Coverage for Android

Tags: android, ant, code-coverage, emma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generating code coverage report for android test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295834/generating-code-coverage-report-for-android-test-project)

I am facing a problem in Emma Coverage for an Android Project.
I am able to generate the build.xml for the Project and the Test Project.
But when I run "`ant coverage`" I do get the following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\HelloAndroidTest\build.xml
BUILD FAILED
Target "coverage" does not exist in the project "HelloAndroidActivityTest".

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Do I need to change my build.xml file for any of the projects?
If Yes, what would be the optimum change?

Comment: Hi Oers...Thank You for your reply... I tried to solve by the solution given by you.. But Still the Coverage folder is not shown.The following details are shown when "ant coverage" is used.Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\HelloAndroidTest\build.xml

coverage:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: Hi..Could u please elaborate more on the solution provided by you.Actually build.xml is auto-generated and can we change that file. I guess if I do use the solution provided by you.. I need to add much more within the target premises..Actually one of my colleagues is able to get Android Code Coverage without this target step.Please do guide me more on this.I shall really be thankful.

Comment: All I did was point out, that your generated build.xml has no coverage target. It is hard to tell why it is missing, because information about creating of this build.xml is missing. Of course you can change the build.xml, to your needs. But what you need and miss may be a completely different question. If you open a new question include your build.xml and describe what you need and what is not working.

Comment: Hi Oers..Thank you for our reply.Please do find the required details.I used android update test-project -m <full path to main project> -p tests(Project Name)/
to create build.xml for TestProject.Here is the build.xml for Test Project.

Answer (score 3):

The newest SDK uses emma by putting emma in front of the build:

```
ant emma debug install
ant emma debug install test
```

The first is run from your project director, the second the test directory.  Doing so will generate the full coverage report.  Note:  That in order for this to work you do need to be running the emulator or a on a rooted phone.

For more details see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html