# Android JUnit report generation

Tags: android, code-coverage, junit4, emma

I have already read answers at

- [generating code coverage report for android test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295834/generating-code-coverage-report-for-android-test-project)
- [Unable to get Emma Coverage for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473852/unable-to-get-emma-coverage-for-android) .

---

I am getting following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "emma" does not exist in the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the log you've posted and the posts you've looked at already, I'm assuming you're running the command:

```
ant emma debug install
```

Your problem can depend on many factors including what android-sdk you have installed. If you have version 13 or less you need to run:

```
ant coverage
```

Please provide more information including what sdk version you are running, the exact command you are running and where you are running it (project, lib-project, test-project)

Comment: I am running on android-14. Mys test project and main project are same. I am running the command in project folder(i.e same as test project).

Comment: If you've set up the project properly the target should exist. From what I've seen it's better practice to split out your test project into a a separate folder within your main project (i.e tests/). Then you'll want to run this in your main folder (you might have to specify a target with `-t`):  
    
`android update project -p .`  
then cd into your `/tests` folder and enter:  
`android update test-project -p . -m ..`  
to point it to your main project. This will also generate you a build xml that depends on the android ant xml which contains the emma target.

Comment: When I have a main project and a different Test project then my Coverage report is generating fine but I am asking how we will do it if we have selected Project under test as "THIS PROJECT" option while creating test project , i.e, my test and main both project are same.Do I have to run both update project and update test project in the same folder? If I do that then ant emma debug install or ant emma debug install test dont work? How to do it in this case.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but if Coverage reporting works with a separate test project, why not do it that way? If I'm understanding you, your setup has both your source files and your test files in the same project (aka in your src dir). This doesn't sound like good practice. Android specifically supports having separate test projects probably so you can easily track what goes into your app and not clutter your core project. See this [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects) on testing setup and structure for more information.